# Erase custom translation

Tags: 6, i18n-l10n

I need to erase a custom translation I made for the Addresses Module. The problem is I changed

> Mexico

to

> México

(with accent) and now, logically, the module does not work correctly since it is looking for the previous value so it can autoselect the states.

Is there a way I can erase the translation? I have tried to search for it but so far, I have not found the right entry.

I am able to use PHPMyAdmin, in case this is feasable thru SQL.

Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

I used a module called [Localization Client](http://drupal.org/project/l10n_client) which provides a user GUI for translations, enable it and go to the page with the translation you should be able to find it in the list then and alter it.

Comment: Yes, I am actually using this module, and I have found translations I've made before and edit them, but I cannot find this specific one. This is exactly the method I am using, Laxman.

Thanx for your input.

Comment: no problem. Also have you looked in the Translations Strings list via the admin area "admin/config/regional/translate/translate"?

Comment: I get a "page not found". I must be missing some module.